# Why my function in C++ is not being executed?

Tags: c++, function, math, project, equation

I have a C++ lab and the problem is this: The user should enter a value for X(X is the number of tests held). If x<15, the program does not calculate anything. If X is between 16 and 30, the program should calculate C=1.0/10.0*(24*A) and if X>30 the program should calculate C=0.15*(24*A). My multiple if code works but when I enter the value for X, the equation is not solved. Does anyone have any idea ??

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //variables defined here
    float A, X, C, F;
    //A stands for number of classes scheduled

    //X is for number of tests and C is the modification 

    cout << "This program predicts the number of cars parked at HVCC at any given hour \n";
    cout << "enter a value for A \n";
    cin >> A;

    cout << "enter a value for number of tests X \n";
    cin >> X;

    if (X < 15)
    {
        cout << "No modificatons needed for under 15 tests \n";
    }

    else if (X > 15 && X < 20)
    {
        cout << "Approximation for between 15-30 tests \n";
        C = 1.0 / 10.0 * (24 * A);
        cin >> C;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Approximation for more than 30 tests \n";
        C = 0.15 * (24 * A);
        cin >> C;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you calculate `C = 0.15 * (24 * A);` and overwrite it in the next step `cin >> C;`? Did you mean `cout << C;`?

Comment: To appear the value of the equation when it is executed

Comment: Why are you computing a value for `C` if you're just going to overwrite it with input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cin >> C; will get the user input for C.
```

change it to `cout << C` in both the else blocks.

Comment: You know you can edit your answers, right? No need to delete and repost to change it. Your deleted posts are visible by anyone with sufficiently high rep.

Answer (score 1):

With `cin` you read user input. With `cout` you print results:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //variables defined here
    float A, X, C, F;
    //A stands for number of classes scheduled

    //X is for number of tests and C is the modification 

    cout << "This program predicts the number of cars parked at HVCC at any given hour \n";
    cout << "enter a value for A \n";
    cin >> A;

    cout << "enter a value for number of tests X \n";
    cin >> X;

    if (X < 15)
    {
        cout << "No modificatons needed for under 15 tests \n";
    }

    else if (X > 15 && X < 20)
    {
        cout << "Approximation for between 15-30 tests \n";
        C = 1.0 / 10.0 * (24 * A);
        cout << C; // replace cin >> with cout <<
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Approximation for more than 30 tests \n";
        C = 0.15 * (24 * A);
        cout << C; // replace cin >> with cout <<
    }
}
```